# Google Cloud firewall

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall

I have this doubt about GCP firewall rules in the default network.
I create two VMs in two different regions inside the same network and so they can ping via internal ip each other. Why if I delete the firewall rule  `default-allow-internal`  they are still able to ping them each other via internal ip?

Instead, if I also remove the  `default-allow-icmp`  rule they are not able to ping each other via internal ip.

Comment: Piing use icmp protocol. Your test is correct, no doubt, it works well!

Comment: While practicing with Google Cloud Firewall rules, create rules (allow and deny) for each of the primary protocols: ICMP, UDP, and TCP (HTTP is built on top of TCP). In normal day-to-day Google Cloud networking, TCP is the most important. UDP is popular with VPNs such as OpenVPN and WireGuard. ICMP is mostly used as a diagnostics tool.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#more_rules_default_vpc) default-allow-internal allows ingress connections for all protocols and ports among instances in the network. If you delete this FW rule instance can be pinged using the FW rule default-allow-icmp and it's intended behavior.

FW rule default-allow-icmp Allows ingress ICMP traffic from any source to any instance in the network.